# haskell binary search tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

```
module Main where

import Data.List
import Data.Function

type Raw = (String, String)

icards =  [("the", "le"),("savage", "violent"),("work", "travail"),
           ("wild", "sauvage"),("chance", "occasion"),("than a", "qu'un")]

data Entry = Entry {wrd, def :: String, len :: Int, phr :: Bool}
             deriving Show

-- French-to-English, search-tree section

entries' :: [Entry]
entries' = map (\(x, y) -> Entry y x (length y) (' ' `elem` y)) icards

data Tree a = Empty | Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a)

tree :: Tree Entry
tree = build entries'

build :: [Entry] -> Tree Entry
build []     = Empty
build (e:es) = ins e (build es)

ins :: Entry -> Tree Entry -> Tree Entry

...

find :: Tree Entry -> Word -> String

...

translate' :: String -> String
translate' = unwords . (map (find tree)) . words
```

so i'm trying to design function ins and find but i am not sure where to start.any ideas?

Comment: You should check out Chris Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf He has great ideas on how to implement all kinds of data structures in Haskell. Hint: it's going to involve recursion.

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, I think an actual tutorial would make more sense than Okasaki's book or thesis.

Comment: @ivanm, he later expanded the thesis into an introductory textbook with exercises and all.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea by which criteria the tree should be sorted, so I use just `wrd`. Then it would look like:

```
ins :: Entry -> Tree Entry -> Tree Entry
ins entry Empty = Tree entry Empty Empty
ins entry@(Entry w _ _ _) (Tree current@(Entry w1 _ _ _) left right) 
   | w == w1 = error "duplicate entry"
   | w < w1 = Tree current (ins entry left) right
   | otherwise = Tree current left (ins entry right)
```

How to get there?

As always when using recursion, you need a base case. Here it is very simple: If the tree is empty, just replace it by a node containing your data. There are no children for the new node, so we use `Empty`.

The case if you have a full node looks more difficult, but this is just due to pattern matching, the idea is very simple: If the entry is "smaller" you need to replace the left child with a version that contains the entry, if it is "bigger" you need to replace the right child.

If both node and entry have the same "size" you have three options: keep the old node, replace it by the new one (keeping the children) or throw an error (which seems the cleanest solution, so I did it here).

Answer (score 2):

A simple generalization of Landei's answer:

```
ins :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
ins x Empty = Tree x Empty Empty
ins x (Tree x' l r) = case compare x x' of
  EQ -> undefined
  LT -> Tree x' (ins x l) r
  GT -> Tree x' l (ins x r)
```

For this to work on `Tree Entry`, you will need to define an instance of `Ord` for `Entry`.